# How to link a server to an ODBC Dsn requiring a password, in SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, odbc

I have an ODBC driver that I would like to use as a linked server in SQL Server, the problem is it requires a password.  I can connect  to the DSN in a c# application like this:

```
OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection("Dsn=OdbcDSN;PWD=blahblah")
```

I have created my linked table in sql server but i just cant figure out how to send the PWD parameter

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'LINKTEST', @srvproduct=N'', @provider=N'MSDASQL', @datasrc=N'OdbcDSN
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try for **System DSN**

```
DSN=myDsn;Uid=myUsername;Pwd='xxx';
```